# How do I fix sed group capturing for unnesting a LaTeX code section?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a piece of text, that I want to unnest.

`\caption[Server HTTP responses]{Server HTTP responses\label{fig:http-status}}`

I want sed to bump the final } so that it starts in front of label like so:

`\caption[Server HTTP responses]{Server HTTP responses}\label{fig:http-status}`

Using a regular expression editor against my test text, it seems that:

```
(\\label\{fig:[a-zA-z0-9 -]{1,}\})\}$
```

replaced with

`\}\1`

would do the trick. This works on debuggex.com and in the Mozilla Regular Expression tester.

When I however test this with sed (I'm a complete newbie with sed, so please go easy on me here), I use

```
cat ./file.tex | sed -e 's@(\\label\{fig\:[a-zA-z0-9 -]{1,}\})\}$@\}\1@g' > test_output.txt
```

which returns: 
`sed: -e expression #1, char 47: Invalid content of \{\}`

**What am I doing wrong here? Is there an easier way to run through a massive text file to replace with regex?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems:

1. Curly braces are not special, don't escape them to get its literal meaning.
2. Same with parentheses, without escaping match literal, escape them for grouping.
3. Colon are not special, don't escape them.
4. Range `A-z` is incorrect.
5. The `/g` flag is not needed to substitute once.

It gets:

```
sed -e 's@\(\\label{fig:[a-zA-Z0-9 -]\{1,\}}\)}$@}\1@' ./file.tex
```

That yields:

```
\caption[Server HTTP responses]{Server HTTP responses}\label{fig:http-status}
```

Comment: +1. Here is a great resource to complete your response http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: That explains my sed breakage, I'll be sure to brush up on specials, assumed } was special as they indicate ranges. Thank you :) I messed up the A-z on retyping.

Comment: @Birei Is the g flag if multiple substitutions should happen in a file?

Comment: @EarlyPoster: The `/g` flag is to do multiple substitutions per line.